# how to output a stream to a variable in Progress 4gl or Webspeed

Tags: stream, progress-4gl, openedge, webspeed

I am trying to output a Stream to a longchar.
Webspeed has a built in Stream {&WEBSTREAM} I am trying to put it into a longchar to do some conditional formatting and then re-stream it to the web server.

I can output the stream to a file like this:

```
hStream = STREAM WEBSTREAM:HANDLE.

OUTPUT STREAM-HANDLE hStream TO VALUE("C:\htm.txt").
```

But that is going to be to slow, (I cant be writing every html page to disk before i manipulate it).

Is their a way to Stream to a variable?

Comment: The only option I can see is to write to the clipboard and the copy from the clipboard to the longchar. That would limited to output <= 64K  in size.

Comment: @Tim Thanks Tim! 
Back to the drawing board for me: I am trying to catch the html before it gets sent to the web server. The reason for this is complex... but basically i want to be able to replace some text in the html with custom text. (Currently doing this on the front end, with js, but would rather do it on the back end do to cross site scripting concerns)

Any words of wisdom will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I would think the generating code could be replaced with a series of concatenations into a LC and then you could do your replacement / manipulation then

Comment: Which way are you generating the HTML in WebSpeed e.g. the CGI wrapper? Your Progress code will generate the HTML that gets sent down the web stream, so you just need to send different HTML to the web stream, using perhaps a function in place of some hard-coded HTML. It's difficult to advise without some sample code.